# Python equivalent of Person-fit Statistics in R

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I am working on some data and i am required to carry out a person-fit statistical analysis in R.
What is the python equivalent module (that can be imported into Jupyter notebook) of person-fit statistical analysis in R?

I looked up google and saw goodness of fit but this is not the same as person-fit analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chuks, unfortunately as far as I know there isn't any direct equivalent in Python to person-fit stat analysis used in R.